# Using inline templates with KendoUI declarative syntax

Tags: html, kendo-ui, visual-studio-2017

I'm using the KendoUI declarative syntax for a toolbar with an inline template. My page loads correctly but the visual-studio syntax checker does not agree; it changes the colors and underlines everything. The HTML tags are causing this and I've tried escaping them multiple ways but can't get the syntax checker to agree; even tried reversing the single and double quotes.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="mainToolbar" data-role="toolbar" data-items='[
                {"template" : "<div>Template Test</div>" },
                {"type"     : "button", "text" : "Search"}]'>
  </header>

</body>

<script>
  var mainToolBarVM = kendo.observable({});

  kendo.bind($("#mainToolbar"), mainToolBarVM);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your attribute definition onto a single line:

```
data-items='[{"template": "<div>Template Test</div>"},{"type": "button", "text": "Search"}]'
```

Visual Studio freaks out due to the tags in your template literal, and it being on another line.